# How can I create a Entry with drop down menu in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

does anyone of you know, how to create a search line, like one with Entry(), with a dropdown menu, like in Google these suggestions underneath that search line????

Please forgive me for errors. I'm completely new with this.

Comment: Use a ttk combobox.

Comment: Bryan Oakley. I already tried but there is always this little arrow showing downwards. I want the drop down menu to appear only if I am clicking at this Entry.

Comment: I dont think there is any widget with such specification, you might have to make a new widget for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a customised combobox without the button. We just remove the button element and reduce the padding. Now it looks like an entry but the dropdown will appear on Key-Down.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    
class HistoryCombobox(ttk.Combobox):
    """Remove the dropdown from a combobox and use it for displaying a limited
    set of historical entries for the entry widget.
    <Key-Down> to show the list.
    It is up to the programmer when to add new entries into the history via `add()`"""
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        """Initialize the custom combobox and intercept the length option."""
        kwargs["style"] = "History.Combobox"
        self.length = 10
        if "length" in kwargs:
            self.length = kwargs["length"]
            del kwargs["length"]
        super(HistoryCombobox, self).__init__(master, **kwargs)

    def add(self, item):
        """Add a new history item to the top of the list"""
        values = list(self.cget("values"))
        values.insert(0, item)
        self.configure(values=values[:self.length])

    @staticmethod
    def register(master):
        """Create a combobox with no button."""
        style = ttk.Style(master)
        style.layout("History.Combobox",
            [('Combobox.border', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
              [('Combobox.padding', {'expand': '1', 'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
                [('Combobox.background', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
                  [('Combobox.focus', {'expand': '1', 'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
                    [('Combobox.textarea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]})]})]})])
        style.configure("History.Combobox", padding=(1, 1, 1, 1))
        style.map("History.Combobox", **style.map("TCombobox"))


def on_add(ev):
    """Update the history list"""
    item = ev.widget.get()
    ev.widget.delete(0, tk.END)
    ev.widget.add(item)

def main(args=None):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.wm_geometry("600x320")
    HistoryCombobox.register(root)
    w = HistoryCombobox(root, length=8, width=40)
    w.bind("<Return>", on_add)
    for item in ["one", "two", "three"]:
        w.add(item)
    w.place(x=0, y=0)
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```